# C# For-Each Controls

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach, custom-controls

i have this code within my Public Form1():

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is CheckBox)
                {

                }
            }
```

what i'm looking to do is trigger an event when any of the CheckBoxes are clicked, it doesn't matter which one. so, for example:

```
if(CheckBox.Checked == True) {
 //do something to the checked checkbox 
}
```

but of course, this throws the error, because i havent specified which checkbox:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CheckBox.Checked'

is there a way around this? Because i have the same event applied to every single checkbox like this:

```
 if (TestBox.Checked == true)
 {//Do Something}
 else {//Do Something}

 if (TestBox2.Checked == true)
 {//Do Something}
 else {//Do Something}
```

which makes my code horridly inefficient.

EDIT: This iteration only loops throug the cb.Checked == false, and ignores the else....

```
foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            if (cb.Checked == false)
            {
                cb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("M:\\Phase IX (Jeremy, Sandima)\\Icons\\ CheckboxUncheck_18x.png");
                cb.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
                cb.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                // make all four (!) BackColors transparent!
                cb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                cb.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
                cb.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }
            else
            {
                cb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("M:\\Phase IX (Jeremy, Sandima)\\Icons\\CheckBox_18x.png");
                cb.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
                cb.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                // make all four (!) BackColors transparent!
                cb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                cb.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = Color.Transparent;
                cb.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for future people reading this,
applying concepts from this thread and others. I left my appearance properties in their own checkchanged events, and instead used this process for my disabled buttons, i made them into a list and proceeded as below:

```
foreach(Control t in Ratingfields)
        {
            if (t.Enabled == false)
            {
                t.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("M:\\DisableBox_18x.png");
                t.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;

                if (((CheckBox)t).Checked == true)
                {
                        t.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("M:\\RadioGreen_Disabled18x.png");
                        t.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;
                    }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to iterate over controls of a specific type - for example, all check boxes:

```
foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()) {
    if (cb.Checked) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: with this,  it only loops through my first condition - answer edited above

Comment: @Krono That's very strange - the other side of the conditional should be hit for checked check boxes. Did you manage to resolve the problem?

Comment: unfortunately no, instead i have left the code as the big mess it is for now, but ive applied the same concept to my disabled buttons, so like:

foreach (var cb in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {if (cb.Enabled == false){//stuff}}
tested in a new clean test project it works, but it doesnt seem to work in my regular project even though it throws no errors

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
List<CheckBox> cboxes = new List<CheckBox>();
cboxes.Add(cb1);
cboxes.Add(cb2);
...
cboxes.Add(cbN);
...
if(cboxes.Any(b => b.Checked))
{
   ...
}
```

Alternatively you may hook into onchange event for all your checkboxes.

Comment: my checkboxes are not meant to be in a list @rbaghbanli

Answer (score 0):

@rbaghbanli's answer is good, it is the proper way to accomplish your task. I just want to point out why you got the error:

You shouldn't use

```
if(CheckBox.Checked == True) {
```

You shall use

```
if(((CheckBox)c).Checked == True) {
```

Comment: if(((CheckBox)Form1).Checked == True) gives me the error 'True does not exist in the current context'

Comment: 1. why you changed c to form1?   2. True ->true

Comment: typo - was trying something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding checkboxes to the form dynamically or  adding manually, just add a single event to all of them

```
Protected void check_checkchanged(object sender, changedeventargs e)
{
var checkedbox  = sender as CheckBox;
//do something 
}
```